# Failed to connect Amazon RDS in AWS Glue Data Catalog's connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I am trying to add an Amazon RDS (Postgres 15) connection in AWS Glue:

[image]

My JDBC URL is

```bash
jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/my_db
```

which I can successfully connect in pgAdmin 4.

However, when I test this connection by

[image]

[image]

I got "FAILED".

[image]

The IAM role I am using even has [AmazonRDSFullAccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AmazonRDSFullAccess.html):

[image]

When I click "View log" button, the error log is not really helpful. It seems AWS has issue parsing the errors:

```bash
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
```

[image]

And here is my Security Group config. Basically both inbound and outbound rules allow all traffic:

Security Group - Inbound rules:

[image]

Security Group - Outbound rules:

[image]

I am wondering what else could cause this connection issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, I found the issue is because AWS Glue is using an old JDBC driver. So I have to upload the latest driver manually to use.

### Step 1. Download latest JDBC driver and upload to S3

Download latest JDBC driver at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/
As of today, I downloaded latest JDBC driver 42.6.0 Java 8 version which filename is `postgresql-42.6.0.jar`.

Then I uploaded at `s3://my-bucket/aws-glue/postgresql-jdbc-driver/postgresql-42.6.0.jar`

### Step 2. Update the JDBC connection

Update your JDBC connection in AWS Glue -> Connectors with

- JDBC Driver Class name: `org.postgresql.Driver`
- JDBC Driver S3 Path: `s3://my-bucket/aws-glue/postgresql-jdbc-driver/postgresql-42.6.0.jar`

[image]

### Step 3. Add new access for the AWS Glue IAM role that is being used

In order to use my own JDBC driver, I need add the following permissions to the IAM role:

- Grant permissions for the following job actions: `CreateJob`,
  `DeleteJob`, `GetJob`, `GetJobRun`, `StartJobRun`.
- Grant permissions for IAM actions: `iam:PassRole`.
- Grant permissions for Amazon S3 actions: `s3:DeleteObjects`,
  `s3:GetObject`, `s3:ListBucket`, `s3:PutObject`.
- Grant service principal access to bucketin the IAM policy and your JDBC driver S3 location.

The default `AWSGlueServiceRole` policy has `CreateJob`, `DeleteJob`, `GetJob`, `GetJobRun`, `StartJobRun`. So I just need provide the rest of access to a new policy `AWSGlueServiceRole-MyPolicy` I created:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/aws-glue/postgresql-jdbc-driver/postgresql-42.6.0.jar",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole-xxx"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now the IAM role have

- The default `AWSGlueServiceRole` policy
- My new policy `AWSGlueServiceRole-MyPolicy`

(Note you do NOT need default `AmazonRDSFullAccess` policy)

[image]

Note the "Test Connection" will still fail with error log

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.glue.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Testing connections with custom drivers is not currently supported.
> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.glue.exceptions.InvalidInputException: Testing connections with custom drivers is not currently supported.

However, the crawler should succeed!

[image]

## Extra Notes

Based on [AWS Glue doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc), Glue 4.0 is using PostgreSQL JDBC driver 42.3.6 which is quite new. However, I am not sure why the connection still failed.

Note my Amazon RDS is using Postgres 15 this case, and my `show password_encryption;` returns `scram-sha-256`. I do not need `set password_encryption = 'md5';` like [some users did](https://repost.aws/questions/QUpkrhcfkYQtS2adbjpQ7quQ/cannot-connect-from-glue-to-rds-postgres#ANzKC5VfBqSkqBR2dM-X0Stw).

## Reference

- https://repost.aws/questions/QUpkrhcfkYQtS2adbjpQ7quQ/cannot-connect-from-glue-to-rds-postgres#AN2SxYJ-3pT425XOS0GhUmQg

Answer (score 1):

For me the core of the issue turned out to be password encryption purely.  Nothing was working with a custom driver.  I reverted to the default driver and simply updated my dynamic user creation to use set password_encryption = 'md5';

It may be that they have recently resolved the default driver issue.  I'd recommend just trying with a user created with md5 pass encryption before anything else and move forward from there.